# CSS - sub menu disappears on hover

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I apologize upfront if this is a simple mistake.

I'm trying to update the code for a css menu with hover effect, and when i hover over the parent li, the sub menu ul appears. When I try to hover to the submenu, it disappears; from what I can understand there's a gab between the parent li and the sub menu.

The code is for the menu is the one below:

```
.site-header{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DADADA;
}

.site-branding{
    width: 30%;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.navigation-container{
    width: 70%;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.main-navigation{
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: block;
}

.main-navigation li{
    display:block;
            border-right: 1px dotted #DADADA;
}

.main-navigation a{
    padding-right:3px;
    padding-left:3px;
    font-size:75%;
    font-weight: lighter;
    display: block;
}

.main-navigation li:last-of-type{
    border-right:none
    }

.main-navigation a ul{
    display:none;
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover ul{
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -150%;
    width:180px;
    position: absolute;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a{
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    width:180px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li{
    font-size:50%;

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please post the HTML too..and if you can please reproduce the issue in a fiddle..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that the issue lies here:

```
.main-navigation ul li:hover ul{
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -150%;
    width:180px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

More usually it would look something like this:

```
.main-navigation ul li:hover ul{
    left: 100%; /* start at the right edge of the parent li */
    top:0% /*always align to the top of the parent li */
    width:180px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Also the parent `li` should have `position:relative`.